# Example of open operator but not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Assume that $T:\ell_1\to\ell_2 $ is bounded,linear and one-to-one. Prove that $T(\ell_1)$ is not closed in $\ell_2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T$ is one-to-one then by closed graph theorem $\ell_1$ may be regarded as a infinite dimensional closed subspaspace of $\ell_2$. Any closed infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell_2$ is $\ell_2$. Thus we conclude that $\ell_1$ is isomorphic to $\ell_2$. This is impossible because $\ell_2$ is reflexive while $\ell_1$ is not.

Comment: I'm sorry,I'm little bit confused, how closed graph theorem is used to know $\ell_1$ is infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell_2$?

Comment: If it were closed, $T$ would be an isomorphism onto its range.

Comment: are you really using the closed graph therorem? How ? If  T is bounded you already know it is continuous.  Then the closed Graph theorem says that $G_T$ is closed in $X \times Y$. Why do we need this theorem? Couldn't we just say that $T$ is an isomorphism onto is range from the start?

Comment: @ConradoCosta One of the equivalent reformulations of closed graph theorem says: if $T$ is closed and one-to-one, then $T$ is an isomorphism onto its range.